# Open video from a URL on webView Iphone

Tags: iphone, video, fullscreen, rotation

In my Iphone app I open a URL on a webview.This URL contains videos. When I open a video it is not played fullscreen and if I rotate the screen it is not rotating. How can I manage this video ? I don't have any player. Can anyone help me ?

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

these two links can help you ... especially the first one..

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html

Answer (score 0):

You do not technically need a "media player", just load a supported media URL into a UIWebView and it should play automatically. I would not recommend making this a habit, but its a quick solution.

Comment: I load the URL into a webview and it works ok, but I need to make video play fullscreen...how can I detect when a video start playing?

Comment: You can add an MPMoviePlayer listener to see when the movie starts playing, see the `MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference` http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

i think your webpage contains `<video>` tag in it. That's why its not getting full screen.

try to play the video with `<a href="url of your video">video</a>`

You will surely get the full screen video

Comment: my webpage not contains <video> tag ...I open a php link